# Django/Foundation - Accordion with table rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, zurb-foundation

I am pretty new on web development and want to make table where the user can click on a row in order to show more details (others rows). I do not know if it is important to notice it but, each row of my table are quiet heavy, they contain :

- [Collapse Menu](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion-menu.html)
- Switch

I followed this [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion.html%20%22%22) to do what I want but it does work. According to this help, it is written

> The container for an accordion needs the class .accordion, and the attribute data-accordion. Note that in these examples, we use a , but you can use any element you want.

So here is my code :

```
<table class="accordion" data-accordion data-accordion>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>XXXX</th>
            <th class="sorttable_numeric">Score</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for X,couples in zipped %}

        <tr data-accordion-item data-multi-expand="true">
            <td>
                <a href="http://www.XXX={{XXX}}">{{XXX}}</a>

            </td>
            <td>
                <body>
                <ul class="vertical menu" data-accordion-menu>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">{{0.295}}</a>
                        <ul class="menu vertical nested">
                            <li>
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        {% for couple in couples %}
                                        <td>{{VINIO}}</td>
                                        <td>{{PINIO}}</td>
                                        <td>{{0.222}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
                            </li>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </body>
                </body>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="switch tiny">
                    <input class="switch-input" id={{ZZZZ}}_{{forloop.counter}} type="radio"
                           name="exampleSwitch">
                    <label class="switch-paddle" for={{ZZZZ}}_{{forloop.counter}}>
                        <span class="show-for-sr">Tiny Sandwiches Enabled</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
            Here should be the content that appears when the user click on the table row. I want this content to be others rows, is possible ?
        </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I do not understand why I do not have a table, with rows where the user can click and expand it to see what the row contains.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to move `{% for couple in couples %}`, outside `<tr>` tag. So it should be  `{% for couple in couples %} <tr><td>...</td></tr>{% endfor %}`. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you but this correction did not correct and solve my problem... Any others suggestions ?

Comment: Umm, is the issue with your django template tags or your Accordion setup? You should first test Accordion alone, once you confirm that the setup is correct and it is working, then bring data from server through Django template tags. I'm not familiar with Accordion so I will have to read the documentation in order to give you more suggestions. Sorry I can't be of more help.